# Serializing Non-Data Classes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, serialization

In a Kotlin library, I have the following class that I want to serialize (preferably with `kotlinx`):

```
class A(
    id: PropertyValue<String>,
    archived: PropertyValue<Boolean>
) {
    val id: String by id
    val archived: Boolean by archived

    constructor(
        id: String,
        archived: Boolean,
    ) : this(PropertyValue.Value(id), PropertyValue.Value(archived))
}
```

However, `Json.encodeToString` method won't work, because this class does not have any serializer. How can I serialize this class?

Comment: Have you marked it with `@Serializable` annotation?

Comment: The class is provided inside the library, I do not have edit access.

Comment: Then you need to write a [custom serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers); [external serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#deriving-external-serializer-for-another-kotlin-class-experimental) can't be auto-generated for it, because its primary constructor has parameters that are not properties